# How to use filtering in datatable server side processing joined tables?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I am trying to find a way to use filter of datatable server side processing joined tables but not working well.
If you have good experience of its, Please help me.

This is column structure.

```
$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'date', 'dt' => 'td_date'),
    array(
        'db' => 'user_id',  'dt' => 'td_username',
        'formatter' => function ($d, $row) {
            $p_general = new General();
            $userInfo = $p_general->getValueOfAnyTable('users', 'id', '=', $d);
            $userInfo = $userInfo->results();
            return  $userInfo[0]->name;
        }
    ),
    array('db' => 'event',   'dt' => 'td_event',),
    array('db' => 'plant_UID', 'dt' => 'td_UID_text',),
    array(
        'db' => 'note', 'dt' => 'td_note',

    ),

);
```

This(below) is working about another fields but not working about "username".

```
$("#col1_filter").keyup(function() {
            var value = $("col1_filter").val();
            if (table.columns(3).search() !== value) {
                           table.columns(0).search(value).draw();
                    }
        });
```

Comment: What are we looking at here exactly? Your 'column structure' is a PHP array. I guess there is a framework involved but you didn't tag that framework in your tags.

Comment: I am using CorePHP.